ClickHouse jdbc how to increase session timetout times while useing Dbeaver
I want to use DBeaver to connect to ClickHouse using the JDBC HTTP interface. However, the session timeout is 30 seconds. I tried adding socket_timeout=300000 to the URL settings, but it was ineffective.
I also attempted to modify the JDBC driver settings to forcibly pass the socket_timeout=300000 parameter in the HTTP URI, but an error occurred, indicating that the server does not support this parameter. Additionally, I tried changing the socket_timeout value directly in the driver settings, but it had no effect.
enter image description here
My question is, is there a way to increase the session timeout time while using DBeaver or DbVisualizer to execute a SQL query? Specifically, how can I specify parameters during the connection to extend the session timeout?
I have tried many different methods, but I still can't solve this problem.

Timeouts are usually caused by the server or network.

Socket timeout affects only:

how long to wait to socket activity in idle state
how long to wait for response from server
These are server params

It sounds like you wanna control the session timeout. Session is controlled by session_timeout=<timeout in ms>
